# Foreach iteration structure show

Tags: php, json, if-statement, foreach

I have some script with `foreach`, see  below, 
my for each always show output 2 - 1 - 3 - 4 - etc from my json object, how to solve my problem,?

```
<?php public function renderLayout3x3($data=array()){
    $output = "<ul>";

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if($value['posisi'] == '1'){
            $output .= "<li><ul>
                                <li>POS:".$value['posisi']."</li>
                                <li>HOSTNAME:".$value['hostname']."</li>
                        </ul></li>";
        }
        if($value['posisi'] == '2'){
            $output .= "<li><ul>
                                <li>POS:".$value['posisi']."</li>
                                <li>HOSTNAME:".$value['hostname']."</li>
                        </ul></li>";
        }
        if($value['posisi'] == '3'){
            $output .= "<li><ul>
                                <li>POS:".$value['posisi']."</li>
                                <li>HOSTNAME:".$value['hostname']."</li>
                        </ul></li>";
        }

        //for debug..
        print json_encode($value['posisi']);
        /*
        Output : "2","1","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"
        Why : 2 - 1 - 3 - etc, not 1 - 2 - 3 - etc 
        */
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";
    return $output;
}

$json_data = '{"ch":"79",
                "ipaddr":"172.16.11.100",
                "hostname":"TMC-MALL01",
                "posisi":"2",
                "monitorid":"17",
                "view_dimension":"2*2",
                "input_ipaddr":""
            }{
                "ch":"78",
                "ipaddr":"172.16.11.99",
                "hostname":"TMC-JSB01",
                "posisi":"1",
                "monitorid":"17",
                "view_dimension":"2*2",
                "input_ipaddr":""
            }{
                "ch":"80",
                "ipaddr":"172.16.11.101",
                "hostname":"TMC-MALL02",
                "posisi":"3",
                "monitorid":"17",
                "view_dimension":"2*2",
                "input_ipaddr":""
            }{
                "ch":"92",
                "ipaddr":"172.16.11.106",
                "hostname":"TMC-PALMA01",
                "posisi":"4",
                "monitorid":"17",
                "view_dimension":"2*2",
                "input_ipaddr":""
            }{
                "ch":"93",
                "ipaddr":"172.16.11.107",
                "hostname":"TMC-PALMA02",
                "posisi":"5",
                "monitorid":"17",
                "view_dimension":"2*2",
                "input_ipaddr":""
            }{
                "ch":"112",
                "ipaddr":"172.16.11.129",
                "hostname":"TMC-R.PRM01",
                "posisi":"6",
                "monitorid":"17",
                "view_dimension":"2*2",
                "input_ipaddr":""
            }{
                "ch":"113",
                "ipaddr":"172.16.11.130",
                "hostname":"TMC-R.PRM03",
                "posisi":"8",
                "monitorid":"17",
                "view_dimension":"2*2",
                "input_ipaddr":""
            }{
                "ch":"114",
                "ipaddr":"172.16.11.131",
                "hostname":"TMC-R.PRM02",
                "posisi":"7",
                "monitorid":"17",
                "view_dimension":"2*2",
                "input_ipaddr":""
            }{
                "ch":"115",
                "ipaddr":"172.16.11.132",
                "hostname":"TMC-R.PRM04",
                "posisi":"9",
                "monitorid":"17",
                "view_dimension":"2*2",
                "input_ipaddr":""
            }';

$render = renderLayout3x3($json_data);
print $render; ?>
```

output always :

```
Output : "2","1","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"
```

Why : 2 - 1 - 3 - etc, not 1 - 2 - 3 - etc

this is other output :
[image: output iteration]

Comment: what is expected o/p

Comment: Show us your original raw JSON structure.

Comment: Your raw json has the posisi in 2-1-3...order thats why

Comment: You get them in that order because thats the order your json has them in. Looping it will not magically sort it for you, you'll have to do that yourself. Also those if statements does as far as I can see the exact same thing, which makes them all redundant. You can cut it down to a single block as they are now.

Comment: @Script47 i am use 'posisi'  for indexing

Comment: add this line before foreach usort($data, function($a, $b){return $a['posisi'] - $b['posisi'];}); to sort the array

Comment: what is your php version .

Comment: corrected formatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because if statements in your code cannot decide in what sequence you output should be.

You can use usort to rearrange the your $data like this,

```
usort(&$data, function($a, $b){return $a['posisi'] <=> $b['posisi'];});
```

Comment: `usort($data, function($a,$b){
   return $a['posisi'] - $b['posisi'];
  });` for php 5.3

Answer (score 0):

you have to sort your array then you can get the sorted array list. you can use ksort() function which will sort your array on key

Comment: Using ksort wouldn't really solve this problem as it's not the key it should be sorted by. Using usort like in the answer from Kris Roofe is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

first thats a wrong json format on your string.
and if your json format was right then just do this

```
public function renderLayout3x3($data=array()){
    $data = json_decode($data); // decode json format to array

    // set posisi as index
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) 
    {
        $data[intval($value['posisi'])] = $value;
    }
    // sort index
    ksort($data);
    // get array values to data
    $data = array_values($data);

    $output = "";

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $output .= '<li><ul>
                        <li>POS:'.$value["posisi"].'</li>
                        <li>HOSTNAME:'.$value["hostname"].'</li>
                    </ul></li>';
    }
    return "<ul>$output</ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: output renderlayout3x3]

my output case after usort is defined.